# Zend framework 2: How to redirect from a plugin?

Tags: php, session, zend-framework2, identity

I worte a plugin `IdentityPlugin` to check login status of a user. If the user session gets logout, I want to redirect them to login page. My code is given below.

```
public function checkLogin($logout=true,$next='login'){        
    if($this->auth->hasIdentity()){            
    }elseif ($logout){
        return $this->getController()->redirect()->toRoute($next);
    }
}
```

in my controller

```
// Check identity, if not found- redirect to login
$this->IdentityPlugin()->checkLogin();
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You're returning a response to the controller but you're not returning it from the controller itself.

For example you could try this is your controller:

```
$check = $this->IdentityPlugin()->checkLogin();
if ($check instanceof Response) {
    return $check;
}
```

A more complex solution could be to stop the propagation of the controller's `MvcEvent`, set whatever response you want, and return directly.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you need to config you plugin in factories in `module.config.php` and pass service manager to `__construct`, like below:

```
'controller_plugins' => array(

    'factories' => array(
        'CheckLogin' => function($sm){
            $checkLogin  = new Application\Plugin\CheckLogin($sm);
            return $checkLogin;
        },
    ),  
),
```

Then in your plugin you will be able to call all you need using service Manager:

```
namespace Application\Plugin;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\Plugin\AbstractPlugin;

class CheckLogin extends AbstractPlugin 
{


    public function __construct($sm)
    {

        $auth = $sm->getServiceLocator()->get("Zend\Authentication\AuthenticationService");

        if( !$auth->hasIdentity()){
            $sm->getController()->plugin('redirect')->toUrl('/login');
        }

    }        

}
```